# PHP variable defaults radio button checked

Tags: php

I have a variable called music.  I would like if that variable = no the no radio button is checked and if it = yes the yes radio button is checked.  Any ideas?  Here's what I have so far but isn't working:

```
<?php
$music = $venue['music'];
echo $music;    
?>

No<input type="radio" name="music"  value="No" <?php  $music == 'No' ? 'checked' : '' ?>/> 
Yes<input type="radio" name="music"  value="Yes" <?php  $music == 'Yes' ? 'checked' : '' ?>/>
```

Comment: you need to also echo the ternary and using `isset()`. What you have now doesn't do much.

Comment: `<?php echo  $music == 'No' ? 'checked' : '' ?>`

Comment: @PavloZhukov that worked thank you so much!  If you add it as an answer and I can mark as correct :)

Comment: @sd0093 as for me better check code byself before public question like this

Comment: [*"Show a person HOW to fish..."*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43610441/php-variable-defaults-radio-button-checked#comment74269741_43610441) I always say, rather than just "throwing" them one.

Comment: I spent 3 hours trying to get it to work by myself. Thanks for the encouragement. @Fred-ii-

Answer (score 1):

You are not outputting the `'checked'` string. Either use `echo` or `<?= ?>`.

For example:

```
No <input type="radio" name="music"  value="No" <?php echo ($music == 'No' ? 'checked' : ''); ?>/> 
Yes <input type="radio" name="music"  value="Yes" <?= ($music == 'Yes' ? 'checked' : '') ?>/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

$music = $venue['music'];;

if($music == "Yes" || $music == "yes")
{
    ?>
    <input type = "radio" checked="checked">
    <label>Yes</label>
   <?php
}else
{
    ?>
    <input type = "radio">
    <label>No</label>
    <?php
}

?>
```

`checked="checked"` sets your radio button to enabled by default

Answer (score 0):

Your  logic  is  correct,  but   you're  just  discarding  the  returned
expressions. You need to `echo`  the string `'checked'`, either with the
language construct  itself or with  the short  echo tags `<?=  ?>`. Some
alternatives:

```
<input type=" ... " <?php echo $music == 'No' ? 'checked' : null ?> />
<input type=" ... " <?= $music == 'No' ? 'checked' : null ?> />
<input type=" ... " <?php if ($music == 'No') echo 'checked' ?> />
```

Answer (score 0):

You just put "checked" : 'checked'

Please find the code below: in my case i have put 'yes' as checked:

```
No <input type="radio" name="music"  value="No" <?php echo ($music == 'No' ? 'checked' : ''); ?>/> 
    Yes <input type="radio" name="music"  value="Yes" <?php echo ($music == 'Yes' ? 'checked' : 'checked') ?>/>
```